# How to insert std:bind as function pointer into constant map

Tags: c++

I'm trying to insert *std::bind* as function pointer into *std::map* so that in later stages I can replace *std::placeholders::_1* with actual parameters based on the conditions.

Below is the function pointer declaration:

```
typedef int (*funcptr)(std::string, int *);
```

And this is how I insert into the map.

```
const std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, funcptr >> lookup {
  {                                        ------ >function pointer as element to the map
    "aclk",
    {   
      1, std::bind(getParam,NONE,std::placeholders::_1) 
    }    ---------------------------------------------------> this part
  }
};
```

**Full code:**

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>


#define NONE "0"

std::pair<int, int> getParam(std::string, int *){ 
   return std::make_pair(1,9);
} 

typedef std::pair<int,int> (*funcptr)(std::string, int *); 

const std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, funcptr>> lookup {
  {
    "aclk",
    {   
      1, std::bind(getParam,NONE,std::placeholders::_1) 
    }   
  }
};

int main()
{
   auto f = std::get<1>(lookup.second);
   int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   f(a); 
}
```

**MY Question:**

One or other I'm getting struck with the compilation errors with the above approach.

Error I'm facing right now is:

```
g++ -std=c++0x bind.cpp
try.cpp:14: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
```

line 14 in the code is

```
try.cpp:14: const std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, funcptr>> lookup {
```

Comment: `std::bind` doesn't return a function pointer, it returns a callable object. Probably it is better to have the `mapped_type` be `std::function<int (std::string, int*)>`, which can store anything callable with the right signature.

Comment: @BoBTFish Tried your suggestion, still no luck.

Comment: In `std::bind` string is bound (to NONE), so your functor takes only `int*` and that is why signature should be: `typedef std::function< std::pair<int,int>(int*) > funcptr;` [Live](https://godbolt.org/z/2XvK6V)

Comment: @BoBTFish Please make that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was stated in comments, `std::bind` returns callable object - it is unnamed class which has `operator()(args)` and it cannot be casted to pointer to function. You need to use `std::function` as wrapper.

Another issue, *string* is bound when `std::bind` is called, so final functor will take only `int*`, typedef for `funcptr` may be:

```
typedef std::function< std::pair<int,int>(int*) > funcptr;
```